# Stopping a thread in an executor service

Tags: java, multithreading

I am faced with a situation where I need to stop a thread of Executor service from running.

I have already read the solution in other posts which says to make use of Future object and cancel the task.

But I rather tried a different approach.

Please can anyone let me know if there is any issue with this approach.

Following is my Runnable class.

```
public class TestRunnable implements Runnable {     
    Thread t;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        setT(Thread.currentThread());

        while(true)
        {
            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
                System.out.println("From Inside thread, Exiting");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setT(Thread t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public Thread getT() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

Following is my main method:

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors; 

public class ruunTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,     InterruptedException {    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();  

        TestRunnable test = new TestRunnable(); 

        service.execute(test);    

        Thread.sleep(1000);            
        System.out.println("About to Interrupt");     

        test.getT().interrupt();  
    }           
}
```

Comment: Err, yes, there is a serious issue: it doesn't stop the thread. It stops the whole JVM. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jbnizet   how is that stopping JVM?

Comment: Alright , but still if you remove the System.exit(0) from the code and put a break statement there then what?

Comment: Do not interrupt the thread directly. Instead interrupt the Future. Otherwise you may interrupt other tasks accidentally.

Comment: Just curious: what urges you to do that?

Comment: @Fildor I have a situation where I need to stop a particular process that the thread is executing.The Runnable task is submitted to ExecuterService so I needed a way to stop the thread .Hence I used the above method.

Comment: @JBNizet any other point you can suggest regarding any issues with the above approach.

Comment: @waltersu Can you give me a scenario where your said issue may arise?

Comment: I get that. What I don't understand is why the **Thread** has to die? Why isn't it enough to end the Task it is executing and have it gracefully return to its pool.

Comment: @Fildor See my comments above :if you remove the System.exit(0) from the code and put a break statement there then what?

Comment: The run finishes and the Thread will return to pool.

Comment: So you have two possibilites: Use `Future.cancel(true)` or give the Runnable a shared flag which you check inside the run method and set to false when you want to end execution. If you have a blocking call inside that run, interruption (cancel(true)) may be your only choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only proper way to do this is to `cancel` the `Future` corresponding to your task and in your task, you should check regularly if the thread has been interrupted or not.

Something like that:

```
public class Task implements Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
            // Check regularly in your code if the thread has been
            // interrupted and if so throws an exception to stop
            // the task immediately 
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                throw new InterruptedException("Thread interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your main code would be:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// My task
Task task = new Task();
// Submit the task and get the corresponding future
Future<?> future = service.submit(task);
...
// Cancel the task which will interrupt the thread that was executing the 
// task if any
future.cancel(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea to stop a thread voluntarily. Your code is not stopping a thread it actually blocking the whole JVM form progressing further. You actually are missing the whole point of the executor service.

The ideology of the executor is that 'I' have an expanding / contracting list of threads that will do the work for you. 'You' just give me individual, mutually exclusive work jobs to action (Runnables or Callables). The main point to understand here is "you don't worry about threads and their life cycle" ... you just create work items and give them to me to execute. If you don't want to execute a work or want to stop in middle call the `cancel` method, else don't worry about it, because once its done 'I' will finish and clean up and provide you the return values if any.

'I' will also manage the thread pool for you but expanding it with more threads when work jobs come in faster and contracting it to lesser threads by "closing idle threads" when jobs are less frequently pouring in.

Now tell me, is it right what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree. But still can you suggest any drawbacks of above approach.

Comment: Your approach or my approach? Your approach is wrong by design. Concurrency should not be implemented that way. In the right approach the doer of the job need not be aware of the intricacies of the job. This also means that you should not dedicate a doer to a job or a type of job. What a job is and how to do it, should be encapsulated inside the job and not with the doer. In his way you can achieve efficient concurrency.

Answer (score -1):

Try to `thread.interrupt()` but it is ***not recommended***.

Comment: Can back that claim up by reference?

Comment: interrupt will not stop a thread.....at best it will pause it for some time till the thread goes back into runnable state and then runs again.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was enough.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Quasar library for threads, works faster that Java native threads and are easier to use. 
http://www.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/

Comment: Even `Fiber` and `Strand` don't allow voluntary stopping. You are not helping the question owner correct his deign problem. Instead you are diverting him to a new library which actually doesn't do what he wants to do.

Comment: This is not about voluntary stopping a thread, just about stopping a thread and this library makes it faster and easier. I didn't used it, I just read some of the documentation and tests and it looks very well.

Comment: manually stopping a thread is same as voluntary stopping it and its not a good thing to do .....specially when the JVM creators and JDK authors themselves say its not.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `thread.stop` , although it will throw threadDeathError which needs to be handled.

If you use `future.cancel`, it will cancel the task but wont kill the thread as thread will go back to thread pool. `Thread.stop` will kill the thread.

Comment: So what dude, it is deprectaed not removed.

Comment: that doesn't mean you abuse it without understanding why it was deprecated.

Comment: and that doesnt mean that you will use offensive language in comments

Comment: what offensive language? 'abuse' is not an offensive word.

Comment: "dude" is not a right way to address someone whom u dont know.

Comment: The thread death error does not need to be handled if you just want the thread to die.

Comment: @Nazgul Thread.stop() was deprecated because if it's used by another thread, it can result in visible data corruption.  Stopping the currently executing thread when no locked objects are in an inconsistent state doesn't have that problem.  Returning from the run() method is generally a better solution, but it's explicitly not what the question asked for; at least this answer answers the question, even if the reasoning behind the question may be bad.

Comment: Thats the point warren. As as evangelist, we should correct when someone asks for help on a wrong design. The question is not being asked for academic evaluation nor is it being asked for API enforcement. Someone is trying to implement something which probably will go to an unfortunate client or reviewer if not corrected. Reading and inferring questions by exact words leads to confusions and wrong knowledge transfers.